# method Get trigger by checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Case:

if user checked the check box, then SEND **method GET** (like submit button, but the trigger is check box).

```
<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">

<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" id="box">Check Me</label>

</form>
```

As i know is use `javascript` using `on.change` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').change(function(){

       // make it Send "GET"(like click submit button) to the url .     
    });
});
```

I still not found the source code for SEND method GET from internet, can any one help me finish the code?, sorry still learning js.

Comment: Don't do that. It is a weird UI which does things people don't expect. Just use a submit button.

Comment: try `$("form").trigger("submit");`

Comment: just `$('#form')[0].submit();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To acheive this, get the form the checkbox belongs to and call its submit method:

```
this.form.submit();
```

… but don't do that. Use a regular submit button. People expect submit buttons to submit forms. They do not expect checkboxes to submit forms.

Comment: Awesome like i need, Thx a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's submit method

```
$('#box').change(function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')) { //check if checked
           $('#form').submit();
       }     
});
```

Comment: Your code sample is incorrect. [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is different from jQuery collection's [`.get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: @Pavlo i didn't write anything about get method

Comment: @murli2308 — Editing your answer [doesn't change what you wrote before](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36543356/3).

Comment: @Pavlo now I realize what I have done wrong before... Thanks you made me to read about get method